# Laravel controller not working condition not working

Tags: laravel-5

I am working like a social media application... but in my controller last else if not working for status upload. but file and video uload working nicely. what is the correct format for this.
here is my controller

```
 public function getclass(Request $request)
{


    if (Input::has('post_comment'))
    {
        $status=Input::get('post_comment');
        $commentBox=Input::get('comment_text');
        $selectedStatus=Status::find($status);

        $selectedStatus->comments()->create([
           'comment_text'=>$commentBox,
           'user_id'=>Auth::user()->id,
           'status_id'=>$status

            ]);
        Flash::message('Your comments has been posted');
        return redirect(route('class'));
    }

    if(Input::has('status-text'))
    {
        $text=e(Input::get('status-text'));
        $rules = [
            'status_text'=>'required|string',
        ];
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);


        if(Input::hasFile('status_image_upload'))
        {
            $rules['status_image_upload'] = 'image';
            $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);
            if($validator->fails())
            {
                $image = $request->file('status_image_upload');
                $imageName = str_random(8).'_'.$image->getClientOriginalName();
                $image->move('status_images', $imageName);
                $userStatus = new Status();
                $userStatus -> status_text = $text;
                $userStatus -> image_url = $imageName;
                $userStatus -> type = 1;
                $userStatus -> users_id = Auth::user()->id;
                $userStatus -> save();

                Flash::success('Your status has been posted');
                return redirect(route('class'));
            }
        }
        else if ($validator->fails())
        {
            $userStatus = new Status();
            $userStatus -> status_text = $text;
            $userStatus -> video_url = $request['video_url'];
            $userStatus -> type = 2;
            $userStatus -> users_id = Auth::user()->id;
            $userStatus -> save();

            Flash::success('Your status has been posted');
            return redirect(route('class'));
        }
        else if($validator->fails())
        {
            $userStatus = new Status();
            $userStatus -> status_text = $text;
            $userStatus -> type = 3;
            $userStatus -> users_id = Auth::user()->id;
            $userStatus -> save();

            Flash::success('Your status has been posted');
            return redirect(route('class'));
        }
    }


        return view('class',[
        'posts'=>status::orderBy('id','DESC')->get()
        ]);
}
```

In this controller
this code not working

```
 else if($validator->fails())
    {
        $userStatus = new Status();
        $userStatus -> status_text = $text;
        $userStatus -> type = 3;
        $userStatus -> users_id = Auth::user()->id;
        $userStatus -> save();

        Flash::success('Your status has been posted');
        return redirect(route('class'));
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that you have two

```
else if($validator->fails()) { 

}
```

Does the $validator->fails() return a BOOL? Can you verify?

Comment: else
        {
            $userStatus = new Status();
            $userStatus -> status_text = $text;
            $userStatus -> type = 3;
            $userStatus -> users_id = Auth::user()->id;
            $userStatus -> save();

            Flash::success('Your status has been posted');
            return redirect(route('class'));
        }  if i give like this it also not working... can u give me the right format please..

Comment: can you echo the result $validator->fails()?

Comment: no sir...i think its not need... i use this coz if i use else if then must need to condition thats why i used it.